# Oracle Function to check for a particular Email Domain Name

Tags: oracle, stored-functions

I want to write a function in Oracle to check for a particular Email domain. like i need to find for gmail
for any other email domain it should return Invalid

If i pass first one it should return Valid and for if i pass Second one it should return Invalid.

Comment: Please show your effort, what have you tried to solve the problem so far ..?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it gets:

```
create or replace function f_validate_domain(i_email_id in varchar2, i_domain_name in varchar2 default 'gmail.com')
return varchar2
is
begin
    return case when instr(i_email_id,'@'||i_domain_name) > 1 then 'Valid' else 'Not Valid' end;
end;


To test:

begin
    dbms_output.put_line(f_validate_domain('axy@gmail.com'));
    dbms_output.put_line(f_validate_domain('axy@gmail.co.in', 'gmail.com'));
    dbms_output.put_line(f_validate_domain('axy@yahoo.co.in', 'gmail.com'));
end;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can work on the below regular expression pattern as per your need. The below code is for demonstration purposes.

```
create function(email varchar2(40)) 
  return number(1)
is
  result number(1) 
begin
   if regexp_like(email, '[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}@gmail.com$') then
       result := 1;
   else
       result := 0;
   end if;

   return 0;
end;
```